# Show valid certificate using the Windows Security's Confirm Certificate popup via java

Tags: java, certificate, jna

I want to show only valid certificates from Windows Security's Confirm Certificate popup, jna library function get all valid and invalid certificates. Is there any way to solve this problem?  [list certificate from Windows Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGVE.png)

```
public static X509Certificate selectCertificate() throws CertificateException {
    var handle = Crypt32.INSTANCE.CertOpenSystemStore(null, "MY");

    try {
        var certCtx = Cryptui.INSTANCE.CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore(handle, null,
                null, null,16 , 0, null);

        if (certCtx != null) {
            try {
                CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(certCtx.pbCertEncoded.getByteArray(0, certCtx.cbCertEncoded)));
                return cert;
            } finally {
                Crypt32.INSTANCE.CertFreeCertificateContext(certCtx);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (handle != null)
            Crypt32.INSTANCE.CertCloseStore(handle, 0);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JNA is just an interface in Java to native APIs -- Windows in this case.  If you have a list of certificates and want to filter by validity you just need a WinAPI function to test that.

[`CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certverifycertificatechainpolicy) appears to meet this requirement. From the documentation:

> The CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy function checks a certificate chain to verify its validity, including its compliance with any specified validity policy criteria.

[This is mapped](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.10.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32.html#CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WTypes.LPSTR-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinCrypt.CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinCrypt.CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_PARA-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinCrypt.CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_STATUS-) in the JNA user-contributed mappings (`jna-platform`) in `Crypt32.java`.

Applying this boolean function as a filter is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I can get the certificate list from window store, after i check and filter it how can i push it and show them

Comment: Looks to me like [CertNameToString](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.10.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32.html#CertNameToStr-int-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinCrypt.DATA_BLOB-int-com.sun.jna.Pointer-int-) might do that.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i mean to display them on the window as a popup. Can you give me some examples, I have seen how to use CertNameToStr but it doesn't seem to be what I mean according to file test jna lib [Crypt32Util](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32Test.java). I tried using CRYPTUI_SELECTCERTIFICATE_STRUCT with java to use PFNCFILTERPROC pFilterCallback but I don't know all corresponding datatypes

Comment: You're asking an entirely different question now.  I'm an expert in JNA, not popups.  You'll get more help asking a new question about popups and showing what you've tried.

Comment: c++ has a CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate function and it is based on the CRYPTUI_SELECTCERTIFICATE_INESS structure, which can be filtered before displaying the certificates. But it seems jna doesn't support CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate function. That's what I tried, I also edited the title of the post. [CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptuidlgselectcertificate) ,[CRYPTUI_SELECTCERTIFICATE_STRUCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptui-selectcertificate-struct)

Comment: The [CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptuidlgselectcertificate) function is in the Windows API and can easily be mapped with JNA.  See [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#jna-is-missing-function-xxx-in-its-platform-library-mappings)